# Is there a way to order items that are filtered in a Laravel Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have the following filter code:

```
$cards->filter(function($card) {
    if(str_contains($card->text, 'white') || str_contains($card->text, 'blue') || str_contains($card->text, 'black') || str_contains($card->text, 'red') || str_contains($card->text, 'green')) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

I'd like to get my results in the order of white, blue, black, red, green. How can I make it so the results are in that order?

Sample card data:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [text] => Flowers are white.
)
```

Comment: `strpos` will return `0` if the string is at the beginning of that haystack. Being falsy, it'll cause your `filter` to filter them out.

Comment: This filter works fine. Just the order needs changing.

Comment: Oh, I reread what you said. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: It doesn't. Can you show us a sample array in the collection.

Comment: That's a good catch. I guess check if it's -1?

Comment: Use Laravel's `str_contains` instead

Comment: Updated. Do you have any suggestions on how to order the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$colors = ['white', 'blue', 'black', 'red', 'green'];

$cards = $cards->filter(function($card) use ($colors)
{
    return str_contains($card->text, $colors);
})
->sortBy(function($card) use ($colors)
{
    foreach ($colors as $index => $color)
    {
        if (str_contains($card->text, $color))
        {
            return $index;
        }
    }
})
->values();
```

Comment: As far as I know `str_contains` even takes an array of needles, so you can shorten it to `return str_contains($card->text, $order)`

Comment: @JosephSilber: Is there a way to also sort by string length before sorting by color?